# Input Type URL - Says "Please enter a URL" if HTTP is not included

Tags: html, forms, url, input

I've been working on a form and run into a snag. I've been using input type="url" so that iPad and iPhones etc all pull up the correct keyboard - and to try and follow the new standards.

I've run into an issue though. On a form where the web address is *not* required - if a user types in www.theiraddress.com most browsers outline it in red/yellow to notify the user they need to enter "http://" before it.

I've used input:invalid css to remove that outline.

However now when the user submits the form, the browser throws an error saying "Please enter a URL".

The field isn't required - I just wanted to make it easier for folks to enter their addresses - but still display the right keyboards on mobile devices etc.

Is there a way to remove this annoying tooltip that prevents users from submitting the form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a novalidate attribute to the form element. Fx:

```
<form method="post" action="/foo" novalidate>...</form>
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-novalidate

Taken from this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3094185/1497627

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, according to the standard, the protocol is required ([Url input field implementation state](http://wufoo.com/html5/types/3-url.html)). You could alternatively use a regexp to validate that field such as `/^(?:(http|https|ftp):\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(\/)?/i`

Answer (score 1):

According to the bottom of the referenced page (http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/3-url.html) you can use the text input type and the inputmode attribute (http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/23-inputmode.html) to get to the keyboard on mobile devices without being fussy about the text field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want that when a user enters the url without http://, automatically adds http:// front of the url so as not to report error

Try this:

```js
//PUT THIS IN HEAD

function check_url(){
    //Get input value
    var elem = document.getElementById("url_input");
    var input_value = elem.value;
 //Set input value to lower case so HTTP or HtTp become http
 input_value = input_value.toLowerCase();
    
    //Check if string starts with http:// or https://
    var regExr = /^(http:|https:)\/\/.*$/m;
    
    //Test expression
    var result = regExr.test(input_value);
 
 //If http:// or https:// is not present add http:// before user input
    if (!result){
  var new_value = "http://"+input_value;
  elem.value=new_value;
    }
}
```

```html
Try to input www.myurl.com<br />
Try to input http://www.myurl.com<br />
Try to input https://www.myurl.com<br /><br />
URL INPUT:<br />
<input type="url" id="url_input" name="url_input" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Submit!!" onclick="check_url()" />
```

Replace `www.myurl.com` with `http://www.myurl.com`

Nothing happens if `http://www.myurl.com` or `https://www.myurl.com`

Note: `http://www.myurl.com` automatically will be converted in `https://www.myurl.com` by browser if `myurl.com` domain support `SSL(https:)`

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yeti82/281a4hs8/