# jquery validate formatting applies automatically and then changes when implemented properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

http://jsfiddle.net/F3h5a/4/

My form is validating without any call to the validate extension. I'm not sure why this is happening but I like how it colors the input box borders and pops up a dialog when the submit is hit and an empty field exists.

However... I need to be able to remove this formatting because the form is re-used and I'm not sure how to do this since I'm not sure how it's being applied in the first place since I'm not using a validator object.

When I apply the validation properly by un-commenting my jquery the formatting no longer applies as desired.

Comment: I'd like to note that there is quite a difference in style between browsers so maybe you just need to handle the sytle in CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to HTML5 and modern browsers :)

The attribute `required="true"` is new in HTML5 and the more modern browsers can handle that and perform some basic validation for you.

You need to add `novalidate` to your form tag `<form ... novalidate>`.

See this SO post on [HTML5 form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)