# Disable HTML5 form validation in Grails Project

Tags: html, forms, validation, grails

I've started to design and implement a blog-homepage in Grails to get practice with Grails development and HTML. I'm not that experienced with HTML4/5 yet.

My problem is that i want to disable HTML5's form validation which standard message is:"Please fill in this field" if the field is required and not filled, and instead use my own custom error-text that can be typed into the file i18n/messages.properties.

I have read these two question on how to disable form validation in plain HTML5 with either [`novalidate=""`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399528/disable-form-validation-in-browser) or [`autocomplete="off"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

I have generated the scaffolded templates in my Grails project, by typing: `install-templates`.

My plan was to change the `_form.gsp` to include either `autocomplete="off"` or `novalidate=""` in the method renderFieldForProperty(), but neither are working.

Hope somebody have solved this problem and want to share knowledge ;)

Edit: Code from scaffolded renderFieldForProperty():

```
private renderFieldForProperty(p, owningClass, prefix = "") {
    boolean hasHibernate = pluginManager?.hasGrailsPlugin('hibernate')
    boolean display = true
    boolean required = false
    if (hasHibernate) {
        cp = owningClass.constrainedProperties[p.name]
        display = (cp ? cp.display : true)
        required = (cp ? !(cp.propertyType in [boolean, Boolean]) && !cp.nullable && (cp.propertyType != String || !cp.blank) : false)
}
    if (display) { %>
<div class="fieldcontain \${hasErrors(bean: ${propertyName}, field: '${prefix}${p.name}', 'error')} ${required ? 'required' : ''}"> <-- At the end of this line i have tried the to attributes mentioned above
<label for="${prefix}${p.name}">
    <g:message code="${domainClass.propertyName}.${prefix}${p.name}.label" default="${p.naturalName}" />
    <% if (required) { %><span class="required-indicator">*</span><% } %>
</label>
${renderEditor(p)}
</div>
<%  }   } %>
```

Above if you scroll right i have written where i have tried the 2 attributes i mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize `renderEditor.template` this file is responsible for render the form fields according to the Domain Class. As example I changed the `isRequired()` method:

```
private boolean isRequired() {
  //!isOptional()
  return false //always return false, not including the required='' in the field.
}
```