# HTML input[type=number] : override arrow behaviour

Tags: html

Is it possible to have an `input` element with `type` equal to `number`, whose arrow buttons would change the value not by `step` attribute, but by other given number?

I need to have a field with step equal to .001, buy I'd like to make +-1 jumps by clicking arrows. (I ask aboout native arrow buttons, of course I can simulate them anyhow, but that's not the question.)

Answer (score -1):

googling turned this up first

```
<input type="number" name="points" min="0" max="100" step="0.001" value="30">
```

Other than that, I guess you'll need to use JS to manipulate the behaviour. Maybe sth like:

```
<input id="example" type="number" name="points" step="0.001" onchange="checkChangedInput();">
<script>
  function checkChangedInput() {
    // check if number got lower or higher
    ...
    document.getElementById("example").value += OldValuePlusZeroPointNineNineNine;
</script>
```

Though I guess using onchange might give unexpected results when sth is being typed in the field. So you should also check if in/decrement was more than your step(0.001).

This might yield some useful information as well: [HTML5 input type=number change step behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738726/html5-input-type-number-change-step-behavior)

Comment: What if the user changes the current value by 0.001?

Comment: maybe use an onclick instead of onchange... Play around a little with what the DOM has in store for you on that particular element... Maybe even ask google...