# HTML input type=number step prevents form from submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in HTML:

```
<input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-group">
```

I want the user to be able to enter a 3-digit decimal number like `1.234` but `step` needs to be `0.1` and it throws an error and prevents the form from submitting.

I've already tried `step="0.100"` but the result was the same.

I also need to validate other inputs so I can't use `no validate` in the `<form>` tag.

What needs to be done?

Comment: Can you explain this in a bit more detail? You say `step` needs to be `0.1`, but it should allow a value like `1.234`. Does this mean you want values like `0.134`, `0.234`, `0.334`, etc? 3 decimals, but a step of 0.1?

Comment: Why not step 0.001 if you want to allow 1.234

Comment: I think maybe you need step="0.001"?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody yes exactly.

Comment: @mplungjan because not all the users use the 3-digit decimal.

Comment: @cloned no I need the step to be 0.1

Comment: then you can't have values like 1.234 . you can have either one or the other, not both.

Comment: @cloned There is no way, even using JavaScript?

Comment: @AlirezaA2F You could completely remove the `step` variable and add eventlisteners to manually manage the step

Comment: @nickzoum Could you explain more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738726/html5-input-type-number-change-step-behavior

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks! I was hoping for a simpler answer but looks like there is no other way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write a small **customized built-in custom element** doing just that:

```js
class MyInput extends HTMLInputElement {
  constructor(step = 0.1, value = '') {
    super();
    this.type = 'number';
    this.step = this.getAttribute('step') || step;
    this.value = this.getAttribute('value') || value;
    this.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      this.value = parseFloat(this.value) + 0.034;
    })
  }
}

customElements.define('my-input', MyInput, { extends: 'input' });

let input = new MyInput(0.1, 1);
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

```html
<!-- if you want to use declaratively: -->
<input is="my-input" step="0.1" value="2" />
<hr />
```

This definitely needs some tweaking, e.g. if the user types in the input, but this should serve you well as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

One thought is you could remove the `step` attribute, disable the +/- slider buttons, and implement your own +/- buttons. Then, when a user clicks those buttons, a JavaScript function is called that retrieves the value in the input area, converts it to a number, and performs the desired step.

You might run into precision issues with using a step like 0.1. In the below snippet I just fixed the number of decimal places to two.

```js
function stepUp(step) {
  let num = Number(document.getElementById('value').value);
  document.getElementById('value').value = (num + step).toFixed(2);
}

function stepDown(step) {
  let num = Number(document.getElementById('value').value);
  document.getElementById('value').value = (num - step).toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stepDown(0.1)">-</button>
<input id="value" type="number" value="0.00">
<button onclick="stepUp(0.1)">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `novalidate` and write your own validation in js for other form fields

```html
<form novalidate>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-group" >
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I also need other inputs to be validated so I can't use ```no validate```.