# Disable validation of HTML5 elements NOT in Form

Tags: html

A form has the possibilities to disable validation.

```
<form novalidate/>
```

Now, I have an HTML5 element **not** in a form. How to disable validation in that situation?

```
<noform>
    <input name="email" type="email"/>
</noform>
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092801/509663

Comment: Firefox validates on change of input. Unfortunately the 'invalid' event is not fired then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want to achieve.  If the `input` element is not in a position to be submitted to the server then it will not trigger the validation process, as your comment seems to indicate you've discovered.  However, the individual `input` element can still be in an invalid state irrespective of that process.  There are a couple of easy solutions to avoid this:

- If you don't want the field's validity state to be evaluated as an email, don't use `type="email"`
- If you need it to be type `email` but don't care about it being a valid email (eg. to trigger a particular keyboard mode on a mobile device) then use CSS to hide the indications.

Here's how to hide the normal firefox red glow:

```
input:-moz-ui-invalid {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

And [here's a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/BSYMZ/).

Comment: Excellent answer!
One thing: Your solution will still show the validation message.
I had to do setCustomValidity(' '); on input. Maybe you can update your example to have the final solution.