# Cakephp form validation using plugin

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using jQuery in my cakephp forms. I want to add validation using the way I have added my plugin. Putting required on selected input element automatic validates it. No matter if I add my plugin or not. I have included js helper..

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js'=>'jQuery', 'Text');
```

Like this. I want to stop the traditional way it follows for auto validation. And put the validation according to my requirement. I know cakephp 1.x version it follows the same way I want. but changes have been made in cakephp 2.x version for it autovalidation ? how can I stop that ?

Comment: Do I understand correctly; you want to perform validation with *JavaScript* only?

Comment: I want to perform the validation using jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML5 form validation

Depending on the browser you're using, the validation-messages you see are probably part of the HTML5 validation performed by the *browser*. Recent versions of Chrome will automatically perform Form Validation for input elements that have a `required` attribute.

You can *disable* HTML5 validation by adding a `novalidate` attribute to the `<form>` tag.

See this question for more information:

[Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)

**Note**

Although validating with jQuery can be a nice addition (from a user-interface perspective), you should **never** rely on validation in the browser *alone*. Always be sure to perform proper server-side validation. In CakePHP this is done in the models, see [Data Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#data-validation)