# Excluding client-side field validation in Grails

Tags: html, grails

I'm developing web application using Grails and I encountered very strange obstacle.
I've created simple form in gsp, one of the parameters to fill up is a number field. I've used grails built-in tag `<g:field type="number" name="orderOfSubpage">` and generated HTML is `<input type="number" name="orderOfSubpage" value="" id="orderOfSubpage">`. Everything seemed to be fine, but when I was testing the form and I put a letter into number field, I got dialog box with a warning saying that I have to put a number in the field.

I've removed all javascript files included into app OOTB and I didn't add any client-side validation on my own.

Finally, the question. How to disable this strange dialog saying: "Please enter a number"? I don't want it to appear in my app.

I'm attaching a screenshot to clarify it better. [image]

Comment: That's an [HTML5 validation message](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#validation) generated by your browser as you said to expect a number

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by HTML5 form validation and not Javascript. Add "novalidate" attribute to your g:form tag to disable the validation.

```
<g:form novalidate="novalidate" ...
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this additional parameter does not disable HTML5 validation for me.

Comment: can you post the resulting <form> tag from your HTML source?