# Disable input validation for input type=number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a numeric input tag in a form element:

```
<form novalidate="">
      <input type="number" data-role="none" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Quantity" class="quantityInput" />
</form>
```

When user types in any `non-numeric` value, the browser validates it and removes the whole text before submit call.

From the suggestions of other answers I tried using novalidate and `novalidate="novalidate"` attributes on the form. I also tried to tap `invalid` events. But nothing seems to work. The browser just removes the whole text if it is `non-numeric` before doing the submit call.

The reason to use input `type="number"` is that I need a quantity field in which user types something like `10 grams` or `23 pcs` etc. So by setting the input `type="number"`, iOS shows the numeric version of the keyboard first.

How do I disable browser validation for input types of number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)

Comment: If you want both `numerical` and `textual` values, you will have to use `text` type instead. The `number` type will only accept numerical value.(literally)

Comment: can you share your input box code so all understand what's wrong?

Comment: Done. Added my input box code in the question

Answer (score 1):

The modern answer (as of 2020) is to use [`inputmode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode):

```html
    <input type="text" inputmode="email">
    <input type="text" inputmode="tel">
```