# How to display cakephp 2.5.3 model validation message.By default it shows html 5 validation message

Tags: html, cakephp

How to display the validation message which is  defined in CakePHP model.When I submit the form , CakePHP model validation works.But validation message for input field is not displayed. It shows HTML 5 validation Message. I want to display CakePHP model validation message. I am using CakePHP 2.5.3

Following is my code block:

Controller:

```
$this->User->set($this->request->data);
    if ($this->User->validates()) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $Email->send();
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been created'));
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, ' . $this->Auth->user('username')));
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be created. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'nonEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A username is required',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => array('isUniqueUsername'),
            'message' => 'This username is already in use'
        ),
        'alphaNumericDashUnderscore' => array(
            'rule' => array('alphaNumericDashUnderscore'),
            'message' => 'Username can only be letters, numbers and underscores'
        ),
    )
```

View:

```
<div id="divfirstname" class="input text required">
                    <label for="UserFirstname">First Name <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                     <?php echo $this->Form->text('firstname');?>
                </div>

                <div id="divlastname"  class="input text required">
                    <label for="UserLastname">Last Name <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->text('lastname');?>
                </div>
                <div class="input text required">
                    <label for="UserUsername">Username <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->text('username');?>
                </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)

Comment: Please consider using the search function or Google next time for this kind of trivial problems. See the linked answer in post above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the validation-block around your save call.

So this is enough:

```
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        $Email->send();
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been created'));
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, ' . $this->Auth->user('username')));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be created. Please, try again.'));
    }
```

CakePHP handles automatically the validation when `Model->save()` is called and displays the error under your input fields. So if `$this->save` fails because of a validation error, cakephp adds `<div class="error-message">Message Text from your model validation array</div>` under the right input field.

Answer (score 0):

You are left with 2 options :

1. Either dont use validation rule in cakePHP which validates on Client side.
2. On DOM ready , call `$("#formId").removeAttr('novalidate');` Like

   `$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#formId").removeAttr('novalidate');
    });`