# How ignore html5 validation when running tests with PHPunit and Selenium2

Tags: php, html, validation, selenium, phpunit

I want to test the server side validation of my php application.so I am running automatic tests with phpUnit and selenium 2.The selenium webdrive fills the form with invalid data to check if the server return a error message but the problem is that the inputs has html5 validation attributes like required = "required" and type = "email" and so the form is never submitted.There is a way to ignore these attributes validators?

Comment: You need to post some code examples, I don't think anyone will be able to help you without more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)

The "novalidate" attribute on the form element should do the trick.