# Removing default error message from angular form on submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

Removing default `error message` from `angular` form on submit

```
<input name="cardrouting" ng-change="cl(rn, 9)"  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default' , allowInvalid:'true'}" ng-model="rn" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" class="form-control" required />
<span class="error-message" ng-show="form.cardrouting.$invalid && form.$submitted && form.cardrouting.$error.required">Please enter a number</span>
```

When i click on submit it always shows the below error message instead of **"Please enter a number"**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Add `novalidate` attribute to `form` element.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)