# Html5 - Remove chrome error of input date when insert incomplete date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a problem with chrome: when I insert an incomplete date in an input date, like "12/dd/yyyy" and I submit the form, chrome shows me an error like

> Please enter a valid value. The field is incomplete or  has an invalid date

[image: error]

Anyone knows how to remove this error and show a custom error with jquery or js, like: "ERROR: The date you entered is not valid"?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advice.

Comment: Can you share the code for your screenshot?

Comment: Seems similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements

Comment: If you want to get rid of Chrome's validation, just don't use `type="date"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `novalidate`. It prevents the automatic browser validation when submitting a form.

This form will not submit if the input is invalid:

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="date"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
<form>
```

This form will submit even if the input is invalid:

```html
<form action="#" novalidate>
  <input type="date"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
<form>
```