# Hide the default HTML CSS | Type=url

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `type=url`, and would like to HIDE not override the default CSS as shown below. I already have my own CSS running, but cannot seem to get rid of the CSS below:

[image]

If there is a line of JS that I can include to do so will be helpful

Reproductive code sample:

Updated reproductive sample. You must click the button to reproduce:

```html
<form id="Submit">
  <div>
    <input id="search" type="url" name="url" placeholder="Test">
  </div>

  <div class=" input-field second-wrap ">
    <button id="button " value="press " type="submit ">
      SEARCH
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <p id="errorMessage ">uhoh</p>

</form>
```

Comment: hi, can you paste the code you're using? Were you looking to suppress a CSS resource that was loaded earlier?

Comment: Include a [example]. (Although it may be obvious in this case) also your browser version?

Comment: No by using the `type=url` in my form, the screenshot above shows. I will post rep code sample

Comment: @IronMan Updated, also see comment above

Comment: @user202729 updated. Also see comment abovce

Comment: Which browser. The issue is not apparent in Chrome or Firefox (https://jsfiddle.net/4abhx5og/)

Comment: I am in Chrome @JonP

Comment: The issue is not apparent in Chrome (Win) with the code you have provided. Also, note you have HTML issues with unclosed tags, and you can't hide CSS , you need to over-write the styles.

Comment: @JonP just added another sample. Can you try>

Comment: Again that does not reproduce the error (https://jsfiddle.net/4abhx5og/) please make sure you fix our HTML errors, ucnlosed quotes and tags etc.

Comment: @JonP Yes it does. When you click the button it shows

Comment: Just tried it myself with the link you provided

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)

Comment: What's the css you're trying to get rid of?

Comment: OK , that's not css , that is inbuilt browser validation due to the `required` attribute.

Comment: @JonP How can I hide that?

Comment: Have a looked at the linked question in the comments. There are many options there. There should be one that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if `...<form id="Submit" novalidate>...` is what you are looking for. This disables browser native HTML5 form validation.

Comment: Yes, but then it submits my form when I do not want it to submit

Comment: Without novalidate it does not submit when a nonvalid is inputted