# HTML custom validity not firing

Tags: javascript, html, domdocument

I need to configure a custom message when form is submitted.

For some reason it shows the default message. I have tried the `oninvalid` attribute as well.

The form on submit calls a `saveChanges()` method that does not include any checks.

It seems like the `inValid` event fires on submit but the custom validity is not set.

```js
input1.classList.add("ip");
input1.setAttribute("pattern", reg4);
input1.addEventListener("input", () => {
    input1.setCustomValidity("");
    input1.checkValidity();
});
input1.addEventListener("invalid", () => {
    input1.setCustomValidity("Invalid IPV4 address");
});
```

I create the element `var input1 = document.createElement("input");` and then add the class and listeners for validity (above).

Create submit button and append all of this to a form, form append to a div.

```js
var submit = document.createElement("button");
submit.setAttribute("type", "submit");
submit.innerHTML = "Save";
form.appendChild(submit);
form.setAttribute("onSubmit", "saveChanges(); return false;");
el.appendChild(form);
```

Comment: `input1.checkValidity()` function returns a boolean value: true when every inputs are valid and false when 1 or more are invalid. Can show me your html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements)

Comment: @PedroFelgueiras Im generating all the input fields by reading a file. ```

Comment: edited the post